# Nodejs and Handlebars - list duplicating on refresh, instead of refreshing

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I've been playing around with Handlebars templating. Current practice is a simple todo list. On first load it's just fine, but if I refresh my page, it doesn't actually refresh. Instead, it duplicates the results of my GET and appends them to the list.

So, first time the list is like:

- Get groceries
- Take kids to soccer

Then upon refresh I get:

- Get groceries
- Take kids to soccer
- Get groceries
- Take kids to soccer

index.js GET method

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let query = "select * from todos";
  db.query(query, function(err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;
    rows.forEach(function(todo) {
      todos.push(todo.todo);
      console.log(todo.todo)
    })
    res.render('index', {
      todos
    });
  })
});
```

index.hbs

```
<h2>Here's some Todos</h2>
<ul id="list">
{{#each todos}}
  <li>{{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems todos is a global variable, or valid outside of the for loop scope. For each query it adds the existing db items in todos. Before calling the loop make sure the todos is an empty list:

```
if (err) throw err;
todos = [];
rows.forEach(function(todo) {
    todos.push(todo.todo);
    console.log(todo.todo)
})
```